# How to inject AutoMapper with Autofac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, automapper, autofac

What is the proper way to inject AutoMapper to other layers?

I read this blog [post](http://ofarooq.com/index.php/configuring-automapper-with-autofac-ioc-container-to-remove-dependency-on-static-mapper/) , but this code cause exception below

> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

when try mapping in service layer.

```
List<StudentViewModel> list2 = _mapper.Map<List<StudentViewModel>>(list);
```

My AutoFac configuration like below:

```
public static class DependencyRegistration
{
    public static void Config()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);


        builder.RegisterType<TypeMapFactory>().As<ITypeMapFactory>();
        builder.RegisterType<ConfigurationStore>().As<ConfigurationStore>().WithParameter("mappers", MapperRegistry.Mappers).SingleInstance();
        builder.Register((ctx, t) => ctx.Resolve<ConfigurationStore>()).As<IConfiguration>().As<IConfigurationProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<MappingEngine>().As<IMappingEngine>();

        //...
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create a map between the types that you are going to convert?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes, I created profile classes and registered them.

Comment: @YacoubMassad 
{"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nStudent -> StudentViewModel\r\nDomainModels.Student -> ViewModels.StudentViewModel\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nList`1[0]\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nSystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Student_56CF505FEBA6F48D4BC49099754F9D134C329E2A4B8BCB2B62D9E22D00950B16"}

Comment: Can you show the code where you create your maps?

Comment: @YacoubMassad
    public class StudentProfiler :Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>();
        }
    }

Comment: @YacoubMassad mapping works correct when using Mapper.Map static method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need to use the `IConfiguration` object that is registered in the container to create the maps like this:

```
var configuration = container.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
configuration.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>();
```

I think that you should be doing this at the start of your application.

Here is a better way (IMO) to configure things in the `Config` method:

```
public static void Config()
{
    var configuration_store = new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers);

    var mapping_engine = new MappingEngine(configuration_store);

    configuration_store.CreateMap<Student, StudentViewModel>();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterInstance(mapping_engine).As<IMappingEngine>();

    //...
    var container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

I am assuming in the last example, that your classes need access only to `IMappingEngine` (and not `IConfiguration`), since your should already setup all mappings in the `Config` method (or some other configuration method at application startup).

Comment: you says do this in profile class? how to get container?

Comment: No, I am suggesting you do this in the `DependencyRegistration` class

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I have some complex profile classes , I think is it a good idea AutoMapper Configs transferred to DependencyRegistration class?

Comment: @ramin_rp, I am not sure I understand your question. But I think that you can easily create another class to register AutoMapper mappings and invoke it from this `Config` method.

Comment: above code cause AutoMapperMappingException
"An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code"

Comment: @ramin_rp, what is the exception message? What line causes the exception?

Comment: Sorry, problem resolved after reinstall AutoMaper package.

Answer (score 4):

.netcore 3
Autofac 5.1.2
AutoMapper 9.0.0
AutoMapperProfiles -> My profile name

```cs
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterType<AutoMapperProfiles>().As<Profile>();
    builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

    builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}
```

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Contrib.Autofac.DependencyInjection